# Better way of limiting the number of indexes in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array that contains 20 indexes and I only want to return the first 10 indexes is there a better way of doing it other than creating a new array with a loop?

```
$i=0;
$newArray =[];
foreach($oldArray as $item) {
  if ($i < 10) {
    array_push($newArray, $item);
    $i++;
  }
}
return $newArray;
```

Comment: A FOR loop may be better in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use may use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php).

```
<?php

$newArray = array_slice($oldArray, 0, 10);
```